# How to fit with a broken power law

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I would like to fit some of my data in MATLAB by using a broken power law.

Is there a built-in function for it?

Comment: I believe that there are no inbuilt functions to do it. You will need to write it your own.

Comment: A simple approach is to apply linear regression to log-log data, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Graphical_methods_for_identification Be aware though that this does not necessarily give an optimal fit: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/115088/power-fit-to-some-experimental-data For better methods, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Estimating_the_exponent_from_empirical_data

Comment: Thank you Ander Biguri and A. Donda